# Unable to run java junit selenium code for my test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, htmlunit-driver

I recorded the testcase steps using Katalon IDE and I was able to play the recording successfully using private browser session.

I now wish to play the testcase in Linux using headless browser.

Hence, I exported my testcase as Java Junit code as below:

```
package pack;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class QScan { 
private static HtmlUnitDriver driver;  
private static String baseUrl;  
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;  
private static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

    public static void testQScan() throws Exception {
   driver.get("https://qualysguard.mybank.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_70d8552f0974");
System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + driver.getTitle());
System.out.println("Entering userName!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("userNameInput")).click();
        System.out.println("Clear userName!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("userNameInput")).clear();
        System.out.println("Title of the page is 2 -> " + driver.getTitle()); 
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        QScan.setUp();
        QScan.testQScan();
        QScan.tearDown();
    }

 private static boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
driver.switchTo().alert();
  return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
return false;
    }
  }

 }
```

I was able to compile the code using the below command.

```
javac -d . -cp /app/Katalon/lib/lib/junit.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/hamcrest-core-1.2.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-java-3.141.0.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-api-3.141.0.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.0.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-support-3.141.0.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.52.0.jar:/app/Katalon/lib/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar QScan.java
```

The url: https://qualysguard.mybank.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_70d8552f0974 is suppose to redirect me to the Active Directory ADFS SSO login page where i have userNameInput and userPasswordInput fields and submit button for signing in.

Running the java code test case gives me the below error:

```
[user1@myhost vapt]$ java pack.QScan
Title of the page is -> null
Entering userName!
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element by id for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage@30af5b6b
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.56.26', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1011)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1725)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1721)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1367)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1721)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:606)
        at pack.QScan.testQScan(QScan.java:82)
        at pack.QScan.main(QScan.java:182)
```

Post researching on internet; I thought that one should wait for the element to load before the click hence, I added the below code before -> driver.findElement(By.id("userNameInput")).click();

See below:

```
driver.get("https://qualysguard.mybank.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_70d8552f0974");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {

        if (second >= 3) fail("timeout");
        try
        {
                   System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + driver.getTitle());
                   System.out.println("second is:" + second);
                   if (isElementPresent(By.id("submitButton"))) break;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                System.out.println("second2 is:" + second);
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("AFTER SLEEP");
    }


    System.out.println("Entering userName!");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userNameInput")).click();
    System.out.println("Clear userName!");
```

However, when I compile and run it simply timesout when it should not. See output below.

```
[user1@myhost vapt]$ java pack.QScan
Title of the page is -> null
second is:0
AFTER SLEEP
Title of the page is -> null
second is:1
AFTER SLEEP
Title of the page is -> null
second is:2
AFTER SLEEP
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: timeout
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at pack.QScan.testQScan(QScan.java:61)
        at pack.QScan.main(QScan.java:182)
```

The below commands affirm that the URL is accessible from the server.

```
[user1@myhost vapt]$ firefox -v
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Running without a11y support!
Mozilla Firefox 60.9.0

[user1@myhost vapt]$ curl -Is https://qualysguard.mybank.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_70d8552f0974
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

Also, the fact that this test case runs fine using Katalon IDE on chrome browser on Windows affirms that the element IDs are correct.

Can you please suggest how can I get this work ?

Comment: I had a similar problem: test case works locally on windows, but not in headless Linux. Still looking for the solution :( . See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629302/selenium-doesnt-refresh-page-on-jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element by id for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage@30af5b6b
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.56.26', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
```

...implies that the **HtmlUnitDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Ghost Browser** session.

Your main issue is seems to be aparent right from the begining as you see:

```
Title of the page is -> null
```

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* with in the *userNameInput* and *userPasswordInput* fields of the website `https://qualysguard.mybank.com/fo/login.php?idm_key=saml2_70d8552f0974` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#userNameInput")));
  element.click();
  element.clear();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='userNameInput']")));
  element.click();
  element.clear();
  ```

**Important**: Ensure that `HtmlUnitDriver()` is not resolved from :

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.141.0** of *2018-10-31T20:09:30* which is almost more then a years older. Ensure that *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Unable to launch HtmlUnitdriver through Selenium 3.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273474/unable-to-launch-htmlunitdriver-through-selenium-3-4-0/50274121#50274121)
- [HtmlUnitDriver does not load javascript when navigating a page from an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724856/htmlunitdriver-does-not-load-javascript-when-navigating-a-page-from-an-url/53744963#53744963)

Comment: your suggestion does not help. I added  the WebDriverWait code right after driver.get and recompiled using selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar but the title is still shows null. Later it throws java.lang.illegalStateException: unable to locate element by xpath for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.unexpectedpage

Comment: @Ashar Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebajanB i see your comments however, i m not aware of how to resolve HtmlUnitDriver() to appropriate  API. Will consult someone knowledgeable of Java to help me before i can update here.

Comment: @Ashar Ensure that HtmlUnitDriver() is not resolved from : `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;` Checkout the relevant discussions.

Comment: After resolving HtmlUnitDriver() to the desired api I m still facing issues getting WebDriverWait to work. Posted progress and new issue faced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059614/getting-error-running-java-selenium-headless-testcase-due-to-classpath-uncertain